# Legal column names in R and consequences of syntactically invalid column names

Tags: r

```
df <- read.csv(
  text = '"2019-Jan","2019-Feb",
  "3","1"', 
  check.names = FALSE
  )
```

OK, so I use `check.names = FALSE` and now **my column names are not syntactically valid**. What are the practical consequences?

```
df
#>   2019-Jan 2019-Feb   
#> 1        3        1 NA
```

And why is this `NA` appearing in my data frame? I didn't put that in my code. Or did I?

Here's the `check.names` man page for reference:

> `check.names`  logical. If TRUE then the names of the variables in the
>   data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically valid
>   variable names. If necessary they are adjusted (by make.names) so that
>   they are, and also to ensure that there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only consequence is that you need to escape or quote the names to work with them. You either string-quote and use standard evaluation with the `[[` column subsetting operator:

```
df[['2019-Jan']]
```

… or you escape the identifier name with backticks (R confusingly *also* calls this quoting), and use the `$` subsetting:

```
df$`2019-Jan`
```

Both work, and can be used freely (as long as they don’t lead to exceedingly unreadable code).

---

To make matters more confusing, R allows using `'…'` and `"…"` instead of `` `…` `` in certain contexts:

```
df$'2019-Jan'
```

Here, `'2019-Jan'` is *not* a character string as far as R is concerned! It’s an escaped identifier name.<sup>1</sup>

This last one **is a really bad idea** because it confuses *names*<sup>2</sup> with *character strings*, which are fundamentally different. The R documentation advises against this. Personally I’d go further: writing `'foo'` instead of `` `foo` `` to refer to a name should become a syntax error in future versions of R.

---

<sup>1</sup> Kind of. The R *parser* treats it as a character string. In particular, both `'` and `"` can be used, and are treated identically. But during the subsequent *evaluation* of the expression, it is treated as a name.

<sup>2</sup> “Names”, or “symbols”, in R refer to identifiers in code that denote a variable or function parameter. As such, a name is either (a) a function name, (b) a non-function variable name, (c) a parameter name in a function declaration, or (d) an argument name in a function call.

Comment: What's the best strategy to deal with this? Other than accepting the default names `X2019.Jan`, `X2019.Feb`? Is accepting the defaults as good as it gets? Not being able to lead a column name with numbers is less than ideal. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JasonHunter What’s the issue with the solutions shown in my answer? I routinely use such column names.

Comment: What do you do when you need to display the names in a formal table or visualization? Do you simply rename the column names at that point in your workflow?

Comment: @JasonHunter I think we’re talking past each other: I *do* use readable names (which are potentially invalid R identifiers) all along in my workflow. So I don’t need to rename the column names for display, since they’re already “pretty”.

Comment: I did mis-read your answer. I was confused as to "what" was a bad idea. I read it as any of your three proposed solutions were "bad" to use, and you were recommending against that. But it seems I can use them, as long as I'm aware of the consequences. Which I now am. Thanks for the followup.

Comment: @JasonHunter Oh, let me clarify this (I will edit the answer): Only the last solution is a bad idea: don’t mix up the syntax for quoted strings and escaped identifiers. Generally, using escaped identifiers is fine, maybe as long as you don’t go overboard (but eh).

Answer (score 3):

The `NA` issue is unrelated to the names. `read.csv` is expecting an input with no comma after the last column. You have a comma after the last column, so `read.csv` reads the blank space after `"2019-Feb",` as the column name of the third column. There is no data for this column, so an `NA` value is assigned.

Remove the extra comma and it reads properly. Of course, it may be easier to just remove the last column after using `read.csv`.

```
df <- read.csv(
  text = '"2019-Jan","2019-Feb"
  "3","1"', 
  check.names = FALSE
  )

df
#   2019-Jan 2019-Feb
# 1        3        1
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider `df$foo` where foo is a column name. Syntactically invalid names will not work.

As for the NA it’s a consequence of there being three columns in your first line and only two in your second.

Comment: May want to add an example of a syntactically invalid name, such as one starting with a numeric