# ggplot not seperating by value - Calling variables that start with numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr, violin-plot

I am trying to create a violin plot with genotype on the x axis and age on the y axis.

My data.frame (df1) looks like this:

```
ID 1kbDel 3kbDel Age
1  WT     Homo      40
2  Het    WT        30
3  Homo   Het       60
```

I tried:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x='1kbDel', y=Age)) + geom_violin(trim=FALSE)
```

Where I also changed the values of age, 1kbDel, and 3kbDel to factors. But instead of creating a plot with 3 violins (WT, Het, Homo), it creates one labeled '1kb'

I also tried changed Wt, Het, Homo to 0, 1, 2 but I get the same behavior, I dont know why

Comment: What happens when you remove the quotes around `'Deletion1'`? Can you provide MWE? Try using `dput()`

Comment: @George Well i used the '' because the name of the variable is 16kb and just 16kb throws an error because an R variable cant start with a number I think

Comment: @George yea so doing ggplot(df1, aes(x=df1$'16kb', y=Age)) + geom_violin(trim=FALSE) works. Just have to figure out how to change the name of the x axis label now do it isnt df1$'16kb'

Comment: maybe you can try `ggplot(df1, aes(x=df1$'16kb', y=Age)) + geom_violin(trim=FALSE) + labs(x = "desired name for x axis", y = "desired name for y axis") `

Comment: You can use backticks to call syntactically invalid names. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54597804/13210554

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backticks to refer to variable name that start with number.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x=`16kb`, y=Age)) + geom_violin()
```